# Quotient map, quotient topology in Banach spaces

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

In Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri's *Classical Banach Spaces I* an operator $T:X\to Y$ is called a *quotient map* if the $\overline{TB_X}=B_Y$ where $B_X$ and $B_Y$ are the unit balls in Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ respectively. The overline denotes closure.

I'm wondering how this definition relates to quotient map and quotient topology in the more abstract setting of topological spaces. For instance, if that condition is met, does $Y$ have the quotient topology induced by $T$? And conversely, if $T:X\to Y$ is such that $Y$ has the quotient topology, is that condition (or a similar one) true?

Comment: Are both $X$, and $Y$ Banach spaces in your definition of $T$?

Comment: @Rustyn Yes, thanks. I edited.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful or nonobvious this is but: Any continuous linear map between Banach spaces is a quotient map iff it is surjective.  This follows from the open mapping theorem.

Comment: This is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/309683/8157 . Any open mapping that is also surjective is a topological quotient map. The linked post proves that a Banach space quotient map is an open mapping. It remains to prove or disprove that a Banach space quotient mapping is surjective. I think that this is false but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Note that, on the contrary, a topological quotient map between Banach spaces that is also linear is automatically an open map (open mapping theorem), and so maps the unit ball onto a dense subset of some ball. Therefore any topological quotient map that is also linear is a scalar multiple of a Banach space quotient map.

Comment: According to my book, the name quotient map comes from the fact that if $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map, $X/ker(T)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $Y$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro "and so maps the unit ball onto a dense subset of some ball" is incorrect, as stated. It is true that the image of unit ball contains a ball in $Y$ of some radius $r$. It is also contained in a ball of some radius $R$. But in general $r<R$. For example, consider the identity map $(\mathbb R^2,  \ell_1) \to (\mathbb R^2,  \ell_2)$: the image of unit ball is not a ball of any radius, and neither is its closure.

Answer (score 3):

This definition of quotient has metric in mind, since we ask a unit ball to be mapped to unit ball. As such, it has a natural generalization to *metric spaces* $X,Y$, but not necessarily to general topological spaces. (What's a generalization of "isometry" to topological spaces?)

Let $B(x,r)$ be the *open* ball of center $x$ and radius $r$, and $\overline{B}(x,r)$ the closed ball of same center and radius. Here are a few slightly different generalizations: we  ask that $f:X\to Y$ is such that for all $x\in X$ and all $r>0$

1. $\overline{f(\overline{B}(x,r))}=\overline{B}(f(x),r)$ (this most closely matches the Banach space condition)
2. $f(B(x,r))=B(f(x),r)$ (such $f$ is called a *weak submetry*)
3. $f(\overline{B}(x,r))=\overline{B}(f(x),r)$ (such $f$ is called a *submetry*).

The third condition is the strongest, and most pleasant to work with in the geometry of metric spaces. On the other hand, 2nd is easier to establish when we don't have compactness. All of them are strong enough for $Y$ to be isometric to the quotient metric space $X/f$ (notation means we identify points with the same image under $f$). This is not hard to prove.

The converse is false. If $Y$ is a quotient of $X$ by some equivalence relation $\sim$, then the quotient map $f:X\to Y$ may fail 1-3 rather badly. Here is an example: let $X$ be the segment $[0,4]$ with the Euclidean metric. Take its quotient by this equivalence relation: $x\sim x'$ iff $x=x'$ or $x,x'\in [1,3]$. The quotient map sends the closed ball $B(2,1)$ to a point, not to any kind of ball of radius $1$.

Special case when the converse is true: $Y$ is the quotient of $X$ by a group of isometries such that the orbits are closed. In this case, the quotient map is a weak submetry (e.g., page 851 of *Handbook of Geometric Topology* by R.B. Sher and R.J. Daverman).

Some names to look up in connection to submetries: Berestovskii, Guijarro, Sharafutdinov, Perelman.